# How to write sql query with LIKE operator for several values and also using LIMIT

Tags: sql, r, clickhouse

I want to write sql query with LIKE operator for several values and also using LIMIT. So, when i try this:

```
SELECT class, message
FROM my_data
WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%' AND message LIKE '%received an answer%'
LIMIT 2
```

I don't get both values. I get dataframe with two rows where message in both rows is equal request was made by user1. How could i write it correct?

desired result is:

```
class               message
request        request was made by user1
received       received an answer by user114
```

i later use this r code:

```
df <- dbGetQuery(dbConnect(...), stri_encode(sql, to = "UTF-8")) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

my data looks like this:

```
date                  class               message
2020-11-01           request        request was made by user1
2020-11-01           received       received an answer by user114
2020-11-01           request        request was made by user45
2020-11-01           error          error with messages occurred
2020-11-01           request        request was made by user413
2020-11-01           received       received an answer by user056
2020-11-01           received       received an answer by user77
2020-11-01           request        request was made by user413
2020-11-01           error          error with messages occurred
2020-11-01           update         data was updated
```

Comment: could you provide the example of source data and the required result?

Comment: @vladimir i added desired result

Comment: @s__ i added it to qeustion

Comment: could you provide the source data not only the desired result?

Comment: maybe need just replace *AND* with *OR*?

Comment: @vladimir i added data

Comment: @vladimir when i do or sometimes both values in column start with received or both with request

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [neighbor](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#neighbor)-function:

```sql
SELECT result.1 as class, result.2 as message
FROM (
  SELECT arrayJoin([(class, message), (next_row_class, next_row_message)]) as result
  FROM (
    SELECT class, message, neighbor(class, 1) next_row_class, neighbor(message, 1) next_row_message
    FROM (
      /* emulate origin data */
      SELECT data.1 as date, data.2 as class, data.3 as message
      FROM (SELECT arrayJoin(
        [('2020-11-01', 'request ', 'request was made by user1'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'received', 'received an answer by user114'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'request', 'request was made by user45'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'error', 'error with messages occurred'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'request', 'request was made by user413'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'received', 'received an answer by user056'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'received', 'received an answer by user77'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'request', 'request was made by user413'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'error', 'error with messages occurred'),
        ('2020-11-01', 'update', 'data was updated')]) as data))
    )
  WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%' AND next_row_message LIKE '%received an answer%'
  )
LIMIT 2  

/*
┌─class────┬─message───────────────────────┐
│ request  │ request was made by user1     │
│ received │ received an answer by user114 │
└──────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: its easier to use UNION ALL for each type separately

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT class, message
FROM my_data
WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%'
   OR message LIKE '%received an answer%'
LIMIT 2
```

I'm thinking the DISTINCT may keep the duplicate class,message combo to appear in the output. Also, you need an OR not an AND, since there isn't one record matching both conditions (at least in the sample data you showed).

CAVEAT - This won't work in every case, since you may have two distinct "requests made" before you have a "received an answer".

Comment: Try the following - 
SELECT class, message, MAX(date) AS mxDate 
  FROM my_data 
 WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%' 
    OR message LIKE '%received an answer%' 
 GROUP BY class,message
 LIMIT 2

Answer (score 0):

Just replace AND with OR so your query will be :

```
SELECT class, message
FROM my_data
WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%' OR message LIKE '%received an answer%'
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @reredf i got the seem result as u desired, check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f213c/1, so the problem is not with sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You need both

1. replace `AND` with `OR`; and
2. include logic to limit to `user1`, it needs to be in the query.

I'll demonstrate using `sqldf` just to get a quick sql query, but this should work in any DBMS.

```r
sqldf::sqldf(
  "select * from df
   where message like '%user1%'
     AND (
       message LIKE '%request was made%'
       OR message LIKE '%received an answer%'
     )
   limit 2")
#         date    class                       message
# 1 2020-11-01  request     request was made by user1
# 2 2020-11-01 received received an answer by user114
```

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01"), class = c("request", "received", "request", "error", "request", "received", "received", "request", "error", "update"), message = c("request was made by user1", "received an answer by user114", "request was made by user45", "error with messages occurred", "request was made by user413", "received an answer by user056", "received an answer by user77", "request was made by user413", "error with messages occurred", "data was updated")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
SELECT class, message
FROM my_data
WHERE message LIKE '%request was made%' 
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT class, message
FROM my_data
WHERE message LIKE '%received an answer%'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yeah i did that